# Error: field has incomplete type in C

Tags: c, struct, enums, typedef

Here's a structure definition in my library (mylib.h):

```
struct Terra {
enum Tipo_terra tipo_terra;
enum Tipo_mostro tipo_mostro;
short tesoro;
struct Terra* terra_successiva;
};
```

Here's the error:

```
In file included from progexam.c:3:0:    
mylib.h:20:18: error: field ‘tipo_terra’ has incomplete type    
mylib.h:21:19: error: field ‘tipo_mostro’ has incomplete type
```

I have used typedef to define 'enum tipo_terra' and 'enum tipo_mostro' just like this:

```
typedef enum { deserto, foresta, palude, villaggio, pianura } tipo_terra;
typedef enum { nessuno, scheletro, lupo, orco, drago } tipo_mostro;
```

And yes, I have (of course) included my library using

```
#include "mylib.h"
```

I have tried to move *typedef* before and after the structure declaration, no changes, same error. Can you help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you have switched type and variables, it should be `enum tipo_terra Tipo_terra` (watch the capitals), I think.

Comment: `Tipo_terra` != `tipo_terra`

Comment: @Dominique You are right, I forgot to mention it! I have also tried to change the definition the way you suggested, but error is still the same (this time it says that 'Tipo_terra' has incomplete type, mind the uppercase T)

Comment: @LorenzoG. As in my answer: remove `enum` keyword inside the `struct`.

Comment: @LPs Just did! Also, commented. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soome problems:

```
typedef enum { deserto, foresta, palude, villaggio, pianura } tipo_terra;
typedef enum { nessuno, scheletro, lupo, orco, drago } tipo_mostro;

struct Terra {
    tipo_terra terra;
    tipo_mostro mostro;
    short tesoro;
    struct Terra* terra_successiva;
};
```

1. You `typedef`ed your enum so the type **must be** used directly, no `enum` prefix.
2. [c](/questions/tagged/c) is case sensistive, so `Tipo_mostro` is different then `tipo_mostro`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem. I did not know that you could avoid using *enum* if you already used *typedef enum*. I know C is case sensitive, but thanks for reminding me, it's always useful. By the way, the library has been written by a teacher.. I only copy-pasted it to fit my project. Weird. Thanks again!

Comment: Prego. ;) BTW `typedef` is used to define a new type, so you can use it as you use `int`, `char` .....

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative answer using `enum` tags instead of `typedef`:

```
enum Tipo_terra { deserto, foresta, palude, villaggio, pianura };
enum Tipo_mostro { nessuno, scheletro, lupo, orco, drago };

struct Terra {
    enum Tipo_terra terra;
    enum Tipo_mostro mostro;
    short tesoro;
    struct Terra* terra_successiva;
};
```

Another possibility is to use both an `enum` tag and a `typedef` as follows:

```
typedef enum Tipo_terra { deserto, foresta, palude, villaggio, pianura } Tipo_terra;
typedef enum Tipo_mostro { nessuno, scheletro, lupo, orco, drago } Tipo_Mostro;
```

Then you could use either `enum Tippo_terra` or `Tippo_terra` in subsequent code, as they are both the same type.

Note that `typedef` does not create a type, it only adds a name to a pre-existing type, or to a newly defined (and possibly anonymous) type.